# Angular Material Templates loaded with webpack doesnt get css applied

Tags: angularjs, webpack, oclazyload

I'm adapting one angular 1 project to use the webpack module bundle system. Almost everything is working as expected, but one material component doesnt get applied well. It is the ***md-input-container***.

What I think it is the cause of the problem: I'm using ***ng-cache-loader*** to load the html templates. So, I think, in someway the tags are not processed or so. Because I put the ***md-input-container*** in the main index.html (which is not loaded by ng-cache-loader) and it works.

Also, I'm using lazy loading of modules and states with ***ocLazyLoad*** and ***ui-router-extras future state***, maybe this has something to do with the problem...

At first I thought it was only css problems, but I have confirmed its not.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This [weird fix](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5318#event-452097685) solved the problem.